Multiple Repositories over Multiple Subdomains with Github Pages
Current Setup
I have multiple repositories setup in Github Pages, with the subdomains:

site.com
foo.site.com
bar.site.com

Intention
There's a new repository that I want to add as a page for one of the subdomains, as foo.site.com/application.
Problem
The repository, when it's build and deployed, is by default sent to site.com/application.
I want it to be deployed as foo.site.com/application.
What I've Tried

Changed CNAME to match foo.site.com. The build fails since foo.site.com already has the target CNAME.
Changed CNAME to specify the URL it should have. The build fails in the same manner as the first.

What I've Read

A previous discussion, however the solution only works when there is one site to deploy to, such as docs.site.com/application. This solution doesn't work when the project has multiple subdomains.
Official Documentation I've looked through: Configuring a Custom Domain, Managing a Custom Domain, Troubleshooting custom domains and Github Pages


If anyone else has found a solution, or if it just isn't possible, please let me know.
Cheers!

I believe what you want is only possible if the CNAME foo.site.com is set on the repository YOURUSERNAME.github.io.

@BenjaminW yeah gotcha, I thought it would be something like that.
